# find out length of last incomplete line of text in container

Tags: javascript

Is there a way, with JavaScript, to find out the rendered width of the (incomplete) last line of text in a container (e.g. in a div)?

For example, suppose I have the following HTML:

```
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: justify">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
```

If the div is not wide enough, the browser will break the text into multiple lines, possibly like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliqua.
```

How can I find out the rendered width, in pixels, of the last line ("dolore magna aliqua.") from JavaScript?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, this could be helpfull, this is what you want ha?

Check live in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdfzp2aa/4/)

```
$(".borded-textbox").each(function(index, elem) {
  $(elem).append('<span class="endline"></span>')
  var endline = $(elem).find(".endline");
//var sizeOfDiv = $(".borded-textbox").width();
  var sizeOfLeftSpace = parseInt(endline.offset().left);

  endline.css('width', parseInt(endline.offset().left));  
   endline.addClass('processed');
  $(".length").append(sizeOfLeftSpace);
});
```

Comment: It was smart +1

Comment: I voted up because of the idea of adding a span. But I double checked now, there are some errors you need to fix so it can work. Look this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdfzp2aa/2/). First, you should use `position` instead of `offset`. Second, you don't need to subtract from parent width. Also I did some golf in the code. Check the fiddle to see if you agree

Comment: Try adding/removing letters in the phrase to see the result.

Comment: Seems to work in reverse, the more letters the smaller the number. `endline.offset().left` by itself should give you the size in pixels of the text.

Comment: @JustinMacArthur Ahaaa I thought he wanted that gap. 
So I edited, it works as he wants now

Comment: @aladin8848 no problem looks good and a fairly elegant solution

Comment: I accepted aladin8848's answer, but as I don't do jQuery (yet?), I added my own answer in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of aladin8848's ingenious idea in pure JavaScript, MWE.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script>
      function lastLineLength() {
        var thisDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#this')[0];
        var tmpSpan = document.createElement( 'span' );
        thisDiv.appendChild( tmpSpan );
        var x = tmpSpan.offsetLeft;
        thisDiv.removeChild( tmpSpan );
        thisDiv.appendChild( document.createTextNode( x ) );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="lastLineLength()">
        <div id="this" style="display: table-cell; position: relative">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```