# Get length of last incomplete line of text in div

Tags: javascript, html

Given a div that contains a lot of text that may or may not wrap, I'm looking for the x position of the end of the text in said div. This is user generated text so I don't know what's going to be in it, and also, it needs to be XSS safe, so I cannot use `<span>` elements in my code because a user could write some script that could execute.

The solutions given here are great, but would allow for unsafe scripts to potentially execute in the browser.

[find out length of last incomplete line of text in container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044692/find-out-length-of-last-incomplete-line-of-text-in-container)

Ideally, I would have a method with a signature something like this:

int getPixelsFromLeftMostSideOfDiv(Element e)

Comment: To be clear any solution that involves `document.createElement('span');` (or any variation thereof) will be flagged by our automated security tool as XSS vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

this should be XSS safe assuming that the way you put the user text on the screen is XSS safe.

It follows your linked solution's method of appending a `span` to the div and getting the x position of that span. Ie

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');

var span = document.createElement('span');
text.appendChild(span);

console.log(span.getBoundingClientRect().left);
```

JSFiddle attached for you to play with

https://jsfiddle.net/1d29c24d/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, our automated security audit tool will flag `document.createElement('span');` as XSS vulnerable.

Comment: fix your automated security audit tool :)

Comment: or alternatively, have the span inside the HTML with a unique id, select it using a document.getElementById and append it